# ALL Djibouti (.dj) domains suddenly no longer being resolved on most devices/DNS (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN)

Tags: domains, domain-registration, top-level-domains, nameserver, dns-servers

.dj domains appear to suddenly not resolve almost anywhere (lots of complaints incoming from users on .dj websites' social media) i.e. http://www.dj http://plug.dj https://click.dj

Going to any .dj domain results in DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

What's happening? When & how will this be solved?

Comment: All 3 of those websites work... so the question is unclear and most likely a temporary DNS issue. If you continue to have issues contact the registrar or the register http://dot.dj/

Comment: @SimonHayter The issues were solved after about 12 hours. The issues were happening for all .dj domains in all countries.